# Dynamic transitions in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I want to be able to use a different transition depending on the state transition. For example, if I go from .one => .three, I want to fade out ViewOne on removal. If I go from .one => .two, I want to move ViewOne to the left on removal. Right now I have something like this (which clearly, only works for a transition from .one => .two):

```
ZStack {
    if state == .one {
        ViewOne()
            .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))
    }

    if state == .two {
        ViewTwo()
            .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))
    }

    if state == .three {
        ViewThree()
            .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .identity))
    }
}
```

How can I dynamically change the transition based on the state?

**UPDATE:**
Here's a more complete example:

```
enum Screen {
    case susi, onboarding, home
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var screen: Screen = .susi
    @State var transition: AnyTransition = .asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if screen == .susi {
                ViewOne()
                    .transition(transition)

            }
            if screen == .onboarding {
                ViewTwo()
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))
            }
            if screen == .home {
                ViewThree()
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .identity))
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                withAnimation(.default) {
                    self.transition = .asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .opacity)
                    self.screen = .home
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for the state?

Comment: I added a complete example, illustrating the desired (but not working) behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61340717/create-a-transition-whose-removal-depends-on-a-state-value-when-the-view-is-rem?

Comment: It's a very good question. As far as I understand, the transition is defined to the view when the view is created, hence changing the transition after the view is created would actually trigger the `removal` transition of the old view (which is the one defined before changing it to fading or moving) hence making it impossible to update the transition property of a view until the next removal. I am curios for a viable solution, too.

Answer (score 2):

For those reading this with the same issue, one solution was toggling the `id` property of a view. Some searching around SO lead me to this technique, which apparently resets the animations for a view.

```
import SwiftUI

enum Screen {
    case susi, onboarding, home
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var screen: Screen = .susi
    @State var transition: AnyTransition = .move(edge: .leading)
    @State var viewId = UUID().uuidString
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if screen == .susi {
                ViewOne()
                    .transition(transition)

            }
            if screen == .onboarding {
                ViewTwo()
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))
            }
            if screen == .home {
                ViewThree()
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .move(edge: .bottom)))
            }
        }
        .id(viewId)
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                withAnimation(.default) {
                    self.screen = .onboarding
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                    withAnimation(.default) {
                        self.screen = .susi
                    }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                        self.transition = .opacity
                        self.viewId = UUID().uuidString
                        
                        withAnimation(.default) {
                            self.screen = .home
                        }
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                            self.transition = .move(edge: .top)
                            self.viewId = UUID().uuidString
                            
                            withAnimation(.default) {
                                self.screen = .susi
                            }
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                                self.transition = .move(edge: .leading)
                                self.viewId = UUID().uuidString
                                
                                withAnimation(.default) {
                                    self.screen = .onboarding
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I ended up instead modifying the `id` of `ViewOne` instead of the entire ZStack, out of fear that doing so would yield some unexpected SwiftUI quirks down the road. Same technique, just applying it to a different view.